# Initial requests at application start

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

At application start I need to get some global constant data with a suspend function (an http request via okhttp, to be more concrete).

What are the current best practices for this task?

When and where the request can be made? Where to store these data? How to access them from fragments?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to this question.

> When?

You would do this on the application launch. To keep it simple, I would call the data after activity creation. While the data is loading, you can show a loading screen.

> Where? & Where to store these data?

The simple answer should be inside a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) class. It will store the data throughout the activity lifecycle.

If you need persistent storage use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) database.

> How to access them from fragments?

You should use a ViewModel class to make any requests that will retain data for the lifecycle of the Activity. The ViewModel class can be referenced from fragments if the ViewModel class is initiated in the fragments parent activity.

Here is a sample of a ViewModel Class with calling data with retrofit (I removed a lot of code to keep it simple. You will need to lookup how to correctly implement your network connections, and pass your provider to a ViewModel wtih a ViewModelProvider).

```
class MinecraftServerViewModel(val server: MinecraftServerRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val minecraftServerDetails = MutableLiveData<MinecraftServer>()

    fun getMinecraftServerDetails(address: String) {
        val response = server.getMinecraftServerStatus(address)
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<MinecraftServer> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MinecraftServer>,response: Response<MinecraftServer>) {
                minecraftServerDetails.postValue(response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MinecraftServer>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
    }
}
```

After the call is complete, I am setting the MutableLiveData, which can be observed in an activity or fragment.

Here is how the ViewModel is initiated inside an Activity and Fragment.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val retrofitService = ServiceMinecraftServer.getInstance()
    private val viewModel: MinecraftServerViewModel by viewModels {
        MinecraftServerViewModelFactory(MinecraftServerRepository(retrofitService))
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       observerData()
    }

    private fun observerData() {
        viewModel.minecraftServerDetails.observe(this, { serverResponse: MinecraftServer? ->
            // Called everytime viewmodel data changes
            // Do Something with data
            // Dismiss loading and show fragment.
        })
    }
}
```

Here is how you can reference that viewmodel and data when initalized in the parent activity

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    val viewModel: MinecraftServerViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observeData()
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        viewModel.minecraftServerDetails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {serverResponse: MinecraftServer? ->
            // Called everytime viewmodel data changes
            // Do something 
        })
    }
}
```

> Just a quick sample of getting data that has okhttp built into it.

Here is a sample of how I am requesting network connections with [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

```
class MinecraftServerRepository constructor(private val service: ServiceMinecraftServer) {
    fun getMinecraftServerStatus(address: String) = service.getMinecraftServer(address)
}

/*
 * Retrofit service to retrieve Minecraft server information
 * Reference Site https://api.mcsrvstat.us/
 */
const val URL_MINECRAFT_SERVER = "https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/"

interface ServiceMinecraftServer {

    @GET("{address}")
    fun getMinecraftServer(@Path("address") address: String): Call<MinecraftServer>

    companion object {
        var service: ServiceMinecraftServer? = null
        fun getInstance(): ServiceMinecraftServer {
            if (service == null) {
                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL_MINECRAFT_SERVER)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                service = retrofit.create(ServiceMinecraftServer::class.java)
            }
            return service!!
        }
    }
}
```